# Read single ApexClass/ApexTrigger metadata files without using retrieve call

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api, tooling-api, retrieve

We are looking to read single Metadata component's files in a quick manner because in our usecase, user would be waiting in screen while we fetch the metadata.

SOAP API `readMetadata` is intended for this purpose but unfortunately it doesn't support ApexClass/ApexTrigger.

Here are the current approaches and its cons.

- SOAP API `retrieve` - This async call works well but is slow
- Tooling API: `retrieve` - This needs id of a apex class/trigger. If we just have name, then we need to make separate query to get that record. Also this api doesn't return the -meta.xml file so you will have to build that file based on information returned, which can be tricky.
- Query `ApexClass`: We can query without needing to know the id but again issue is getting the -meta.xml

Are you aware of any other APIs that we can use to quickly fetch metadata content for a single component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following format to get any record without using an ID:

```
/services/data/vXX.X/*/sobjects/**EntityName**/**ExternalIdField**/**ExternalIdValue**
```

For example, you can use:

```
/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/Demo
```

Or:

```
/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/Demo
```

Notably, `Name` is an External ID on virtually all objects that have a Name field, including `ApexClass` and `ApexTrigger`.

The Tooling API returns a property called `Metadata` that has the exact same contents as the `-meta.xml` file, including the active status and package version settings.

Example:

```
/services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/Demo
```

Output:

```
{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "ApexClass",
    "url" : "/services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/01p3i00000Bn9d2AAB"
  },
  "Id" : "01p3i00000Bn9d2AAB",
  "NamespacePrefix" : null,
  "Name" : "Demo",
  "ApiVersion" : 55.0,
  "Status" : "Active",
  "IsValid" : true,
  "BodyCrc" : 1.361333916E9,
  "Body" : "public class Demo {\n\n}",
  "LengthWithoutComments" : 22,
  "CreatedDate" : "2022-09-25T15:34:32.000+0000",
  "CreatedById" : "0053i000001Zzz4AAC",
  "LastModifiedDate" : "2022-09-25T15:34:32.000+0000",
  "LastModifiedById" : "0053i000001Zzz4AAC",
  "SystemModstamp" : "2022-09-25T15:34:32.000+0000",
  "ManageableState" : "unmanaged",
  "SymbolTable" : {
    "constructors" : [ ],
    "externalReferences" : [ ],
    "id" : "Demo",
    "innerClasses" : [ ],
    "interfaces" : [ ],
    "key" : "Demo",
    "methods" : [ ],
    "name" : "Demo",
    "namespace" : null,
    "parentClass" : "",
    "properties" : [ ],
    "tableDeclaration" : {
      "annotations" : [ ],
      "location" : {
        "column" : 14,
        "line" : 1
      },
      "modifiers" : [ "public" ],
      "name" : "Demo",
      "references" : [ ],
      "type" : "Demo"
    },
    "variables" : [ ]
  },
  "Metadata" : {
    "apiVersion" : 55.0,
    "packageVersions" : [ ],
    "status" : "Active",
    "urls" : null
  },
  "FullName" : "Demo"
}
```

The `Metadata` property shown here is literally a JSON-formatted version of the `-meta.xml` file. It contains everything you need. You also get the `Id` of the class so you can use it with the [MetadataContainer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacontainer.htm) and related features (in this case, an [ApexClassMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexclassmember.htm)).

Note that the Tooling API is built to support IDE-style development. It's used by the internal Developer Console that Salesforce provides, and there are other IDEs out there that use this API as well. Whenever you need metadata-level information for code in real-time, the Tooling API is almost always the correct solution.

You can also use a Tooling API query:

```
/services/data/v54.0/tooling/query?q=select+fields(standard),metadata+from+apexclass+where+name%3d'demo'
```

Which gives you output like this:

```
{
  "size" : 1,
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "queryLocator" : null,
  "entityTypeName" : "ApexClass",
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "ApexClass",
      "url" : "/services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/01p3i00000Bn9d2AAB"
    },
    "Metadata" : {
      "apiVersion" : 55.0,
      "packageVersions" : [ ],
      "status" : "Active",
      "urls" : null
    },
    "Id" : "01p3i00000Bn9d2AAB",
    "NamespacePrefix" : null,
    "Name" : "Demo",
    "ApiVersion" : 55.0,
    "Status" : "Active",
    "IsValid" : true,
    "BodyCrc" : 1.361333916E9,
    "Body" : "public class Demo {\n\n}",
    "LengthWithoutComments" : 22,
    "CreatedDate" : "2022-09-25T15:34:32.000+0000",
    "CreatedById" : "0053i000001Zzz4AAC",
    "LastModifiedDate" : "2022-09-25T15:34:32.000+0000",
    "LastModifiedById" : "0053i000001Zzz4AAC",
    "SystemModstamp" : "2022-09-25T15:34:32.000+0000"
  } ]
}
```

Note that "Metadata" is a special field. It works **only** when you're retrieving one item at a time. If you try more than that, you get:

> When retrieving results with Metadata or FullName fields, the query qualificatio​ns must specify no more than one row for retrieval. Result size: 3

Comment: Thank you, that confirms tooling api is the best choice for us to retrieve ApexClass/Trigger but could use SOAP Api readMetadata to read single metadata about any other components.

Comment: @metasync Many components are available in the Tooling REST API. readMetadata is a lot slower, as it has a different purpose.